# how to replace default navigation portlet with my template

Tags: python, plone

can anyone tell how to replace a navigation portlet with my own template. I did like this

1. I created one new class for portlet in my .py file and its look like below

   ```
   class navigation_address(Renderer):         
         index = ViewPageTemplateFile('templates/portlet_address.pt')
   ```
2. I registered the portlets in overrides.zcml like

   ```
   <plone:portletRenderer
     portlet="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.INavigationPortlet"
     class=".browser.createPictMenu.navigation_address"
     />
   ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a "navigation address"? You aren't trying to override a portlet to make it a completely different type of portlet I hope? Like you tried with the viewlets before?

Comment: Please provide an error description in your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `plone:portletrenderer` you  just have to specify the origin portlet like you did, the new template and a layer (So it's only active on your plone site if your custom package is installed).

```xml
<include package="plone.app.portlets" />

<plone:portletRenderer
   portlet="plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation.INavigationPortlet"
   class=".my.module.MyRenderer"
   layer=".interfaces.IMyPackageLayer"
   />
```

```py
from plone.app.portlets.portlets.navigation import Renderer as NavigationRenderer


class MyRenderer(NavigationRenderer):

    _template = ViewPageTemplateFile('template/my_navi_template.pt')
```

`<include package="plone.app.portlets" />`makes sure the portlets stuff is loaded.

The browserlayer is registered with GenericSetup:
Place a browserlayer.xml in your profile:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layers>
    <layer name="my.package.layer"
           interface="my.package.interfaces.IMyPackageLayer" />
</layers>
```

And the interface:

```py
from zope.interface import Interface


class IMyPackageLayer(Interface):
    """Request marker interface"""
```

Comment: @@mat: I did the changes as you told but its not working in my case. I cant able to replace the navigation portlet.

Comment: @@mat: I m sure i included this package <include package="plone.app.portlets" /> in overrides.zcml

Comment: Can post any traceback? Make sure your zcml is getting loaded. You don't have to load this in a overrides.zcml.

Comment: @@mat: i checked that my .zcml is loaded. but now i m getting this error ValueError: ('No such file', u'/home/oomsys/brundelre3/src/bdr.theme/src/bdr/theme/templates/replace_page.pt')

Comment: @@mat:I have a replace_page.pt in browser/template/replace_page.pt.. but the error shows browser folder is not in the path..

Comment: @@mat: I have one doubt why we to have specify the <template = "templates/replace_page" directly.. First of all need to override an existing portlet template which is in plone.app.portlets

Comment: Generally if you only overrides the template you don't have to specify a new class. I just saw that the Navigation portlet works a little bit diffrent. I updated my answer

Comment: @@mat: i searched for NavigationRenderer class from navigation.py to adapt in my .py file but i dint find any like that

Comment: @@mat:may i know where is that NavigationRenderer from

Comment: @nirmala I'm sorry I usually import classes this way, the code is more readable (updated the answer)

Comment: @nirmala Another update to the code example (register the browserlayer)

Comment: @@mat: Thanks for your help. I edited my code with your help and from net i picked some solutions for my problem and its working